# To 'if' or not to 'if'

Tags: java, servlets, if-statement

I have written a code and I can't explain why is it not behaving the way it should. I know this sounds silly but it is not.

```
            boolean verify = EDV.verifySignature(signature, cipherText,
                    SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY);
            out.println("Validity " + verify);
            if (verify) {
                // //message is authentic
                String decryptedMessage = EDV.decrypt(cipherText,
                        SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY);
                out.println("Message : " + decryptedMessage);
            }else
            {
                out.println("Signature did not match");
            }
```

This is a simple code that verifies signature and then decrypts the message if the signature is valid(verify is true)

The output of this code is this :

```
Validity false
Signature did not match
```

The message decrypts just fine.

The problem is that the signature should verify (I have checked the signature, cipherText, and key over n times). Here's the kick.

The almost same code

```
                boolean verify = EDV.verifySignature(signature, cipherText,
                        SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY);
                out.println("Validity " + verify);
//              if (verify) {
                    // //message is authentic
                    String decryptedMessage = EDV.decrypt(cipherText,
                            SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY);
                    out.println("Message : " + decryptedMessage);
//              }else
//              {
//                  out.println("Signature did not match");
//              }
```

and Voila!, output is as I wanted it to be and as it should be.

```
Validity true
Message : This is a sample Text
```

And, the first code works just fine on Eclipse, but running it on JAVA servlet is the only time I get this.
Also, the first time I run the code#2 it gives false but after that it gives true.

I can't seem to explain the reason.

**LINKS**

[Code#1](http://52.10.254.136:8080/Incoming?message=jBLQjm6ig9N1TFCFm84PBgmy6uHhSPnhlGYqAlhOZ6hyjYV7DQt7HyuiTq6N6zlUUWEA9O0%2F2V%2BYH5qL7fBfK3%2FzXnZbRJ%2FQgFimuPC0ma8A8RaOPtNdZO0QQvay%2BkOTAI6wcqP%2Byx3XMn4FJiO3b%2FGPcqi7iT0ffYGMQuV1XNI%3D&signature=Sn%2Bh%2BnML7lcHAS4zeGQQYRr9q4tc89cf9VGbB1RI1Ux1LMiqOjDmz%2Fe%2FKQweFmGkNX1bWSs8wr%2BjPaIyqOUfEdE%2FfFUWE6DgADSUsHRMLJXMZhmKnk1%2BZOGXU4hZt8zCpHuxVmnWObagFucYdmL3HTlz9yxatJnF7%2BPY4%2FWdik0%3D)

[Code#2](http://52.10.254.136:8080/Incoming2?message=jBLQjm6ig9N1TFCFm84PBgmy6uHhSPnhlGYqAlhOZ6hyjYV7DQt7HyuiTq6N6zlUUWEA9O0%2F2V%2BYH5qL7fBfK3%2FzXnZbRJ%2FQgFimuPC0ma8A8RaOPtNdZO0QQvay%2BkOTAI6wcqP%2Byx3XMn4FJiO3b%2FGPcqi7iT0ffYGMQuV1XNI%3D&signature=Sn%2Bh%2BnML7lcHAS4zeGQQYRr9q4tc89cf9VGbB1RI1Ux1LMiqOjDmz%2Fe%2FKQweFmGkNX1bWSs8wr%2BjPaIyqOUfEdE%2FfFUWE6DgADSUsHRMLJXMZhmKnk1%2BZOGXU4hZt8zCpHuxVmnWObagFucYdmL3HTlz9yxatJnF7%2BPY4%2FWdik0%3D)(Run this code, it gives false validity refresh it and it turns true)

Comment: It gives true right away on both links.

Comment: And what exactly is the difference between the two codes? They look identical.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Mine doesn't. How is that possible. only code#2 give true and that too on refreshing many times. The difference is that I commented the if statement.

Comment: How come verify is false in the first code but it turns our to be true in the second ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer [I'm not lying, here's the screenshot.](http://i59.tinypic.com/209ox3c.png). It happens each time I restart the tomcat service.

Comment: I  don't think you are lying. The problem is just not in the piece of code you gave. It is elsewhere. And it is almost impossible for us to guess where.

Answer (score 1):

Something's not initialising properly in the code just before the sample you gave. Try adding some test println statements for the signature, cipherText and SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY parameters.

Also, check the initialisation of EDV.verifySignature.

Comment: all the variables are well assigned, if they weren't they code would not have worked in the first place. I have check conditions of each variable.